# Monitor only works if Legacy BIOS (CSM) disabled?

Tags: multiple-monitors, uefi, intel-graphics, secure-boot

I have an Asus Q550-LF computer running Windows 8.1 Enterprise. It has a MiniDisplayPort output which is connected to a MiniDP to DVI adapter. I discovered that my monitor was not working the same day I turned off SecureBoot and turned on Legacy mode. On a whim, I re-enabled SecureBoot/disabled Legacy mode and my monitor magically works. It might be worth mentioning that the monitor isn't even DETECTED when SecureBoot is off/Legacy mode is on. It's shown nowhere in any driver config areas.

This leads to two questions:

1. Why does this happen? (I am using latest drivers)
2. How on earth would I fix this?

***Update (8/17/14)***: Thinking about it, this problem seems to be caused more by CSM/Legacy Mode than Secure Boot. I have yet to test this idea though.

***Update 2 (8/17/14)***: Testing the system shows that *it is the fault of CSM/Legacy mode instead of Secure Boot.* The system works fine when Secure Boot is off. It breaks when CSM/Legacy mode is on.

Comment: Are you sure, it is just the display that's not working? Is the OS booting up normally?

Comment: Does SecureBoot changes your resolution ?

Comment: @jjk_charles, the OS does boot up normally (as far as I can tell. No driver errors or anything)

Comment: @Dwza SecureBoot changes nothing except whether my external monitor works or doesn't.

Comment: @Mew any specific reason for you to turn off SecureBoot or turn on Legacy Mode?

Comment: @jjk_charles Hirens Boot CD among other things. It might involve my deep-seeded hatred for EFI.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it appears that the laptops primary display still works but not the external monitor that is connected to the Mini DisplayPort through adapter. Follow the below steps to see if it helps,

- Disconnect the external display
- Restart Windows, and disable SecureBoot from BIOS
- Once you are logged into Windows, re-install the display drivers
- Restart Windows
- Connect back the external display

Apparently, few drivers are required to be re-installed after turning-off/on SecureBoot ([Ref](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481258.aspx))

Comment: I have tried this, and it does not work at all. I also updated the drivers at the time.

Comment: @Mew Have you tried updating your BIOS?

Comment: The bios is the latest version. I tried that already.